# How to use Django Subquery inside Annotate and Sum

Tags: python, django

I am trying to calculate total revenue for a day. Each DailyTotal contains a count of items sold (items_sold) and a Price those items were sold that day (items_price) (every items is sold for the same price all day). That part is working, but now I need to convert multiply that value by the exchange rate for that day/country.

```
rate = ExchangeRate.objects.filter(  
    date=OuterRef('date'), 
    country=OuterRef('country')))  

calc_with_rate = Sum(F('items_sold') * F('items_price') * Subquery(rate.values('rate')), output_field=FloatField(),)  

results = DailyTotal.objects.filter(**query_filters).annotate(
    revenue=calc_with_rate)
```

but I get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'NoneType
```

I assume it is because rate.values('rate') is not returning a an int..
but I can't do

```
rate.values('rate')[0]
```

or I get:

```
This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

so I am not sure how to complete this query?

Comment: You could do: first annotate the `rate` you get with the `Subquery` and then annotate the calculation for `items_sold * item_price * subquery_result`. Then you can sum it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to += with an int and a NoneType - i.e. one of those two variables is returning empty, and you're trying to add them - since you're not doing it explicitly with a += operand in the code above, I'm assuming it's happening somewhere in the Sum().  Debug what it does there and you'll likely find the issue.